# Help with \column in beamer class

Tags: beamer

I have a small problem with the \column command in the beamer class.

Up to now, it has worked perfectly but somehow a problem with the spacing has appeared.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\frametitle{Argumente}

\begin{columns}[c] % The "c" option specifies centered vertical alignment while the "t" option is used for top vertical alignment

    \column{.45\textwidth} % Left column and width
    \centering \textbf{Pro}
    \vspace{0.2cm}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Vergleichbarkeit mehrerer Studien gewährleistet
        \item Entscheidungshilfen für gesundheitspolitische Fragen
        \item Überblick über Forschungslage
    \end{itemize}

    \column{.45\textwidth} % Right column and width
    \centering \textbf{Kontra}
    \vspace{0.2cm}

    \begin{itemize}     
        \item \enquote{Äpfel-Birnen Problem}
        \item \enquote{Garbage in - garbage out}
        \item \emph{Publication bias}       
    \end{itemize}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end {document}
```

It looks like this. I think the problem is quite obvious. I would like to make the "Pro" and the "Kontra" as well as the items appear in one line 
[image: What it looks like]

Thank you very much for your help.

Helena

Comment: Does `\begin{columns}[t]` do what you want?

Comment: Unrelated to the alignment you are asking about, but your code does not compile due to the missing `csquotes` package and you should only use the `fragile` frame option in frames where you really need it, not in a simple frame with columns and normal text.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @samcarter I think this is a duplicate of some other question (to be honest I found this out after searching in the site). I'll leave it to our `beamer` expert to choose what to do ;)